# How to prevent the user from inputting strings in MIPS

Tags: string, input, mips, system-calls

I'm trying to make a program where the user inputs a integer, not a string. Thing is, if the user actually puts a string, I get an error. Is there any way to prevent the user from inputting a string?
Here's the code I'm using to test:

```
        .data

    Output_1: 
        .asciiz "\Enter a number: "

        .text
        .globl main

main:   la $a0, Output_1
        li $v0, 4
        syscall

        li $v0, 5
        syscall
```

Comment: Use syscall 8 ("read string"), then parse the string that you get to see if it contains any disallowed characters. If it doesn't, convert the string into an integer.